# Rails 4: ActionController::ParameterMissing param is missing or the value is empty: youtube_vid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud

Alright guys,

I don't know why my new/create actions are giving me trouble right now, but I am getting the following error. Any ideas as to why? Thank you in advance.

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in ArtistYoutubeVideosController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: youtube_vid
```

And it highlights these lines of code:

```
def create
    @youtube_vid = ArtistYoutubeVideo.new(youtube_vid_params)
    if @youtube_vid.save
      redirect_to artist_youtube_videos_path
    else
      render :new
    end
end

 def youtube_vid_params
    params.require(:youtube_vid).permit(:id, :video_name, :video_url)
 end
```

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"HGnaAPOrw8Fbz7/dR12GXRoo6ZWByCbqN5L15C0D5yxBlpLy0afRkVaJ1peJkt1pB+tqZaytgJPJTNPoEl54yg==",
 "artist_youtube_video"=>{"video_name"=>"test 11",
 "video_url"=>"test 11"},
 "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

ArtistYoutubeVideosController.rb

```
class ArtistYoutubeVideosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @youtube_vids = ArtistYoutubeVideo.all
  end

  def new
    @youtube_vid = ArtistYoutubeVideo.new
  end

  def create
    @youtube_vid = ArtistYoutubeVideo.new(youtube_vid_params)
    if @youtube_vid.save
      redirect_to artist_youtube_videos_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def youtube_vid_params
    params.require(:youtube_vid).permit(:id, :video_name, :video_url)
  end
end
```

artist_youtube_videos/new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Youtube Vids</h1>

<%= form_for(@youtube_vid) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :video_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :video_name %>

  <%= f.label :video_url %>
  <%= f.text_field :video_url %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

<% end %>
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "artist_youtube_videos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "video_name"
    t.text     "video_url"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :artist_youtube_videos
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per params you've posted, change

```
  def youtube_vid_params
    params.require(:youtube_vid).permit(:id, :video_name, :video_url)
  end
```

to

```
  def youtube_vid_params
    params.require(:artist_youtube_video).permit(:id, :video_name, :video_url)
  end
```

and you'll be good.